# Auto reconnecting VPN in Ubuntu >18.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, internet

I have my VPN set to auto-connect on startup/initial wifi connection which is great:

[image: vpn autoconnection]

However, sometimes the VPN fails (I am not sure how to emulate this), and instead of trying the whole connection again, it falls back to an unsecured connection instead of retrying the VPN. I would prefer it to cut out completely than go to my normal connection and could not find a way to do this. Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would by to create a VPN kill switch with `ufw`.

First of all set up your VPNs through NetworkManager (or whatever you are using) if you haven't already. Then

1. Install `ufw`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ufw
```

2. Enable `ufw`

```
sudo ufw enable
```

3. Allow access to your local network (optional but recommended)

```
sudo ufw allow in to 192.168.X.0/24
sudo ufw allow out to 192.168.X.0/24
```

Your IP probably looks something like this but to be sure check `ifconfig` for `inet addr:...`.

4. Now we want to block all connections by default expect the VPN. To do this run

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
```

Am not familiar with pureVPN but, they probably offer a variety of `.ovpn` to set up your VPN easily.

5. Find the ovpn file you are using and check its contents

```
cat file.ovpn
```

6. You should see a line saying something like

```
remote 123.456.789.10 1194
```

7. So to allow access to this address run

```
sudo ufw allow out to 123.456.789.10 port 1194 proto udp
```

Note: Protocol (`proto`) is `udp` for port 1194 or `tcp` for port 443.

7. You can check your configuration with

```
sudo ufw status
```

Note: In case you want to, you can always disable `ufw` simply by running

```
sudo ufw disable
```

but make sure to re-enable it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try those steps tomorrow. Do you know by any chance how to simulate the VPN failing?

Comment: You could try simply deactivating the VPN... As you will see, you won't be able to access the internet. For a quick test try pinging a website with `ping -c 5 archlinux.org`

Comment: Works great, thank you!